# Set AVCapture to 60 FPS,iOS, Swift 4

Tags: ios, frame-rate, avcapturesession

Im trying to set my backcamera that is set as 1080p to 60 FPS but the code and tutorials cycle through the camera formats before it sets the fps.

Is there a way to set the fps without it cycling through all the different formats? it takes a long time cycling through them and sometimes crashes.

below is my code

```
func setFPS() {
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
//      var finalFormat = AVCaptureDevice.Format
    var maxFps: Double = 0
    for vFormat in backCamera!.formats
    {
        print("Tony active formats are: \(vFormat)")
        var ranges = vFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges as [AVFrameRateRange]
        let frameRates = ranges[0]
        if frameRates.maxFrameRate > 30
        {
            maxFps = frameRates.maxFrameRate
            do {
            try backCamera!.lockForConfiguration()
            backCamera!.activeFormat = vFormat
            backCamera!.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60)
            backCamera!.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60)
            backCamera!.unlockForConfiguration()
            print("Tony the Max FPS is \(maxFps) fps"); //prints 60 fps
//              finalFormat = vFormat
            }catch {
                print("Error on frame rate")
            }
        }
    }

    print(String(maxFps) + " fps"); //prints 60 fps
    print("Tony the FPS is \(backCamera!.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration.timescale) fps") //prints 60 fps


}
```

Comment: What keeps you from setting activeFormat, activeVideoMinFrameDuration, activeVideoMaxFrameDuration manually ? You can debug that for loop and take the values that you need.

Comment: if i dont do it through the loop it seems to crash

Comment: it tells me that this is my active camera on my back camera aon iphone 6s 'Tony active formats are: <AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1c4009510 'vide'/'420f' 1920x1080, { 3- 30 fps}, HRSI:4096x2304, fov:58.632, supports vis, max zoom:16.00 (upscales @1.94), AF System:2, ISO:23.0-736.0, SS:0.000013-0.333333>'